# IOException Adventure

Tags: java, linux, ioexception, shell

I have my java process(in my system) trying to talk to a shellscript(details1.sh),which is in /tmp dir of a remote system(of course the 2 systems are connected). But i am getting this exception-

java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/tmp/details1.sh": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory

I've changed the permissions to 777 also..

But I'm not able to figure out how to get through this one.
Any idea??

Comment: What do you mean by `the 2 systems are connected` ?  The IOException seams to tell that `details1.sh` is not found in your local `/tmp`.  If the root (`/`) of the remote system is mounted in `/mount/remote_sys`, you should run `/mount/remote_sys/tmp/details1.sh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably invoke the shell (e.g. `/bin/bash`) directly, passing the script to execute as the filename.

EDIT: As per comments, this *may* not be the problem - but it's certainly what I'd try first.

Another edit: You appear to be trying to run `/tmp/details1.sh`, but you say that's in the `/tmp` directory *of a remote system*. Obviously if you try to just run `/tmp/details1.sh` it's going to look in the *local* `/tmp` directory... how are you expecting it to know about the remote system?

Comment: In C, and on Linux, the `system` function of stdlib uses `/bin/sh` to call the command.  Of course, Java is not as specific of how a command is run using `Runtime.exec`, but I would expect the same as in C.

Comment: @jfgagne: I'm not sure I'd have any expectations either way, to be honest... but I think it would at least be worth trying.

Comment: @jfgagne You have no *proof* that Java calls system(). In fact it calls one of the exec() family. Just like system() does actually.

Comment: @EJP: True, I have no proof that Java calls `system()`.  But the Linux man says that `system()` calls `/bin/sh -c` to execute its command.  I do not have the Windoze manual, but I suppose (expectations are misleading as Jon stated) that `cmd` or another command interpreter is used to execute the `system()` command.  You are right though that Linux `system()` probably uses a `fork()`/`exec()`/`wait()`, but the binary that is run by `system()`'s exec in Linux is `/bin/sh`.

Comment: Finally, the Linux man says that `exec` function family is a front-end for the function execve, and the execve man says that its filename must be a binary **or a script starting by `#! ...`**.

Comment: @jfgagne this is all irrelevant unless Java calls system(), which it doesn't. system(3) has to call fork(2)/exec(2) because it is a library function and they are system calls, and the only way in which that library function can implement its functionality. Not 'probably' but *definitely.*